# Unable to scroll on page from listview

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

[image]

So this listview is dynamically loaded from api, when I scroll on page (up/down) outside of listview it works perfectly, but when I scroll from inside listview I am unable to scroll on the page. Any ideas on what I can change?

Comment: Can you provide sample code snippet that will reproduce this issue? More about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have used Nested ListView.
Just declare:

```
ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
```

And call _scrollController to both the properties of contoller in listviews.

Answer (score 0):

I think setting the primary property to false in the listview will solve your problem